# Issue while trying to connect to Red5 server

Tags: java, red5

I have installed `Red5 1.0.1`. I am writing a client in Java to connect to the `Red5 server using RTMPT`. I have already developed an application and it is working fine. From my client, I have this line to connect:

```
public class MyRTMPTClient extends RTMPTClient {

    public void start() {
        connect(host, port, app);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRTMPTClient obj = new MyRTMPTClient();
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

This is what is printed in console:

`16:00:11.963 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connect server: 10.81.144.180 port 8088 application installer
16:00:11.970 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connect server: 10.81.144.180 port 8088 application installer connectCallback null
16:00:11.971 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connect server: 10.81.144.180 port 8088 connect - params: {objectEncoding=0, app=installer, flashVer=WIN 11,2,202,235, fpad=false, tcUrl=rtmpt://10.81.144.180:8088/installer, audioCodecs=3575, videoFunction=1, pageUrl=null, path=installer, capabilities=15, swfUrl=null, videoCodecs=252} callback: null args: null
16:00:11.981 [main] INFO  o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - rtmp://10.81.144.180:8088/installer
16:00:12.262 [main] DEBUG o.red5.client.net.rtmpt.RTMPTClient - Created connector Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
16:00:12.354 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Get connection: {}->http://10.81.144.180:8088, timeout = 0
16:00:12.356 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 40
16:00:12.357 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - No free connections [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088][null]
16:00:12.357 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Available capacity: 2 out of 2 [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088][null]
16:00:12.357 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Creating new connection [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088]
16:00:12.379 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to 10.81.144.180:8088
16:00:12.420 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
16:00:12.442 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
16:00:12.442 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:00:12.443 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:00:12.443 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
16:00:12.443 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /open/1 HTTP/1.1
16:00:12.445 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "POST /open/1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.446 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Length: 1[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Host: 10.81.144.180:8088[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Red5 Server)[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /open/1 HTTP/1.1
16:00:12.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
16:00:12.448 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Cache-Control: no-cache
16:00:12.448 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 1
16:00:12.448 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: 10.81.144.180:8088
16:00:12.448 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Red5 Server)
16:00:12.448 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "[0x0]"
16:00:12.462 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.466 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.467 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.467 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.467 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Type: application/x-fcs[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.467 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Length: 14[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.467 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 10:30:12 GMT[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.468 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "[\r][\n]"
16:00:12.469 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
16:00:12.469 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
16:00:12.469 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
16:00:12.469 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
16:00:12.469 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Cache-Control: no-cache
16:00:12.470 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: application/x-fcs
16:00:12.470 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 14
16:00:12.470 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 10:30:12 GMT
16:00:12.479 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
16:00:12.490 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "MJVBMAV5ABPSW[\n]"
16:00:12.490 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Released connection is reusable.
16:00:12.490 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Releasing connection [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088][null]
16:00:12.491 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Pooling connection [{}->http://10.81.144.180:8088][null]; keep alive indefinitely
16:00:12.491 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
16:00:12.501 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmpt.RTMPTClientConnector - RTMPT handling exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MJVBMAV5ABPSW"
      at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48) ~[na:1.6.0_07]
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447) ~[na:1.6.0_07]
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497) ~[na:1.6.0_07]
      at org.red5.client.net.rtmpt.RTMPTClientConnector.openConnection(RTMPTClientConnector.java:161) ~[red5-client-1.0.jar:1.0]
      at org.red5.client.net.rtmpt.RTMPTClientConnector.run(RTMPTClientConnector.java:92) ~[red5-client-1.0.jar:1.0]`

From the exception and the source code in https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/client/trunk/src/main/java/org/red5/client/net/rtmpt/RTMPTClientConnector.java, it looks like Red5 server is returning a `String` as client id where as the `RTMPTClientConnector` expects an `integer`. What am I missing here? If there is a simple tutorial to show how to use RTMPTClient, it would be helpful. I am a beginner.

Please let me know what I can do about this exception as this comes from the `red5-client.jar`

Comment: did you try to connect to the same server and app using a flash client for test?

Answer (score 0):

The string return for the session or client id is correct and should be seen in all the newer versions of Red5 server and client.